# Projects built on the Tendermint platform?

Tags: alternatives, proof-of-work

The [Tendermint](http://tendermint.com/) project sounds like a very promising  proof-of-stake implementation.  What public projects are being built on this platform?

Answer (score -1):

CyberMiles is using it. They just got on the stage

Comment: What do you mean by "they just got on the stage"?

Comment: I mean they are listed on exchanges